# MySqlHelper class + asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql

Hai Guys,
          Like DataAccessApplicationBlock for .net with sql server,Is there any thing for MySql with .net... If so please let me know....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this CodeProject article: [Integrating MySql with Enterprise Library for .NET Framework 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/MySql_with_Ent_Lib.aspx)